# mechitzah, shul and wedding

Tags: halacha, synagogue, wedding, mechitza-partition

1. I read somewhere that a *mechitzah* is technically something required only in a *shul*. Is there a *halachic* source for this?
2. I read somewhere that the concept of *mechitzah* has been extended to include weddings etc. to prevent *kalus rosh*. Where is the *halachic* source for this?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9480/is-a-mechitza-required-for-dancing-at-jewish-weddings-why

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14452/when-is-a-mechitza-required-at-a-meal

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14453/5323 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10795/5323 related to the first question